# React: State in State?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new in react.
What should i do to display a state in dynamic context?

In the example, when **props.something** changes, set displayed text **state1** depending on the **props.something** value. 
If **props.something** is NOT 1, put a checkbox named **checkbox1** in **state1** and show the checked state.

Actually in this case, **checked** state doesn't change even if the **checkbox1** was clicked.

Any ideas?

```
const Child = (props) => {
   const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
   const [state1, setState1] = useState(<></>);
   useEffect(() => {
       if(props.something === 1){
           setState1(<div>something is 1!</div>);
       }
       else{
           setState1(<div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onChange={() => 
                   setChecked((prevState) => return !prevState;)
                 } defaultChecked={false} />
                State is {checked ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"}
            </div>);
       }
   }, [props.something]);

   return (<>{state1}</>);
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks to give some suggestions!

In actual project, the Child component is used to show data-fetching state -- Parent component fetches some data from the online database. Parent component sends "props.something === 1" to the Child if the app starts to fetch data, and sends except 1 when the task was done.
I use **checkbox1** to delete the item got from the database.

Comment: What is the purpose to put DOM Element in the state?

Comment: You can change the DOM Element based on props.something like : return (<>{props.something === 1 ? (<div>something is 1!</div>) : (<input {...props} />)</>

Comment: You are confusing yourself with react and vannila. Its JSX https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html. Get to know the power of JSX,it will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the right approuch to this situation, you can conditionaly render things with the states, is not needed that you use a state to keep your html I did a bit of refactor on your code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function App() { // app is the main component
  const ChildrenComponent = ({something}) => { // destructuring Props
    
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(0); // just a normal state

  useEffect(() => {
    setState1(something); // set the state when the props change
  }, [something]);

  return (
    <>
      {state1 === 1 ? ( 
        <div>something is 1!</div>
      ) : ( 
        <div>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            name='checkbox1'
            onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
            defaultChecked={false}
          />
          State is {checked ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
  

  return <>
  <ChildrenComponent something={1}/> // test1
  <ChildrenComponent something={2}/> // test2
  </>
}
```

on this script we have a childrenComponent that can be imported or defined in the same file, that component get a 'something' prop and set a set based in that. Then render conditionaly the text or the checkbox usin a ternary operator.)

Comment: Here you render component 2 times to show data which you can do only with checking props

Answer (score 0):

You can just check `props` to understand what you need to render.

```
export function App({ something }) {
    
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  if(something === 1){
    return  <div>something is 1!</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type='checkbox'
        name='checkbox1'
        onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        defaultChecked={false}
      />
      State is {checked ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'}
    </div>
  )
}
```